# What is "mit drin"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A Die Chefin episode had this sentence among the subtitles:

> Vielleicht hängt der mit drin.

"mit drin" appears most peculiar to me and I would like to find an authoritative reference that explains the grammar of this usage. Neither Duden nor DWDS associates hängen with "mit drin". The only reference I have found to it is in Reverso where it is translated as "implicated", giving 2 examples in context. I have not found a reference that translates **hängen** as *to implicate*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [zusammenhängen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammenhaengen_zusammengehoeren_betreffen): *A hängt mit B zusammen.*
> A is related to B.
> A is connected with B.

That would be my guess. There is a certain connection and I think that is what you mean.

---

> "[mit drin hängen](https://www.korrekturen.de/synonyme/mit+drin+h%C3%A4ngen/)" / "mit drinhängen" (colloquial language): *In einer Sache mitdrinhängen*
> Being involved in something 
> [to be complicit in sth.](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?lang=de&noframes=1&service=&query=mit%20drin%20h%E4ngen&optword=1&optcase=1&optpro=0&style=&dlink=self)

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Vielleicht%20h%C3%A4ngt%20der%20mit%20drin):

> Vielleicht hängt der mit drin.

> Maybe he's involved.

Here is an example from [Tagesschau](https://www.tagesschau.de/kommentar/wirecard-ausschuss-103.html).

Comment: Excellent! Yes, looking for drinhängen showed an identification with drinstecken, which is found in Duden, although the translation to "complicit" does not appear to be there. Thank you for providing so many great references.

Comment: The best way to show your appreciation of @choXer answer is to up-vote the answer and, if you think that it is correct, to mark it correct by clicking the big tick!

Answer (score 0):

"mit drin" means being included.

"mit drin hängen" on the other hand means being involved in a crime, conspiracy or alike.